# Remove navigation arrows from embedded Flickr image

Tags: html, image, flickr

I hosted images on Flickr and used the following HTML code in Survey Monkey to show an image in the response section of a multiple choice question:

```
<iframe src="https://www.flickr.com/photos/128329805@N07/15472931866/player/" width="75" height="31" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/z2ejhx8f/)

The image appears however, a set of arrows appear over the image - they look like scrolling arrows. For some users, once the images load, the arrows appear briefly and then disappear. However, for other users, the images load and the arrows load and are static - they do not go away. This is not ideal since the arrows cover the image and make them not visible.

It does not seem to be a browser issue, since users tested using both Chrome and IE8. Has anyone had a similar experience with Survey Monkey? Any idea how to remove these arrows?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the page on the demo I added to your question, you can see that Flickr adds the overlay navigation dynamically. There doesn't seem to be a way to avoid this when using the iframe embed method.

However, you can use the HTML embed method instead, which is also available in the Share dialog:

```
<a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/128329805@N07/15472931866" 
    title="10-2-2014 9-36-26 AM-0000 by Leanne Rayo, on Flickr">
    <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2946/15472931866_e6db07ce2a_t.jpg" 
        width="75" height="31" alt="10-2-2014 9-36-26 AM-0000"></a>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/z2ejhx8f/1/)

If you'd rather it not be a link, just remove the two anchor tags:

```
<img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2946/15472931866_e6db07ce2a_t.jpg" 
    width="75" height="31" alt="10-2-2014 9-36-26 AM-0000">
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/z2ejhx8f/2/)